# Handling remote desktop file transfers from RDP session to physical PC and vice versa

Tags: automated-tests, file-handling, file-transfer, remote-desktop, terminal-server

What I'm currently trying to solve is how to handle remote desktop file transfer from RDP session to physical PC and vice versa.

I have few terminal servers and I wanna be able handle/log those file transfer, because data loss prevention, and after that automatize that process. Idealy with pythonic way, but in the end, it actually doesnt matter.

I've really tried google it, but without any reasonable results for me.

Any ideas are welcomed :)

Comment: Hello & welcome to Stack Overflow @dropthebeat! Please see the **[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** article before posting next time.
Also consider clicking **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47220056/edit)** on
your question and make sure you have a valid **[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**, 
else, no one will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the .RDP file.
Click "Edit".
Select the "Local Resources" Tab.
Under Local devices and resources ...
Click the <kbd>More...</kbd> button.
Expand the Drives(+) list and check the local drive you want to see in you remote session.

If you had checked the "C: drive" and your PC name was "TI994A" then the drive will show up in your RPD session as "C on TI994A".

Comment: Thanks for reply Chris. Sure, this way cover the scenario that user transfer files to connected device. But I need to cover almost the scenario that real user can copy/move files without connected device, right through ctrl+c/x, outside the RDP window to physical PC.